# Sending IP in the request header NPM

Tags: node.js, api, express, npm, npm-request

I am trying to send the server's IP (in this case, my computers public IP) to another server in a HTTPS request to get access to their API. I have completed the server authentication and I have my bearer token. I am using an Express and NPM for server side programming. I am getting my IP address as follows:

```
var ipAddress;
publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
  ipAddress = ip;
  console.log(ip);
});
```

I am making my request as follows.

```
request({

  //Set the request Method:
  method: 'POST',
  //Set the headers:
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': "bearer "+ token,  //Bearer Token
    'X-Originating-Ip': ipAddress  //IP Address
  },
  //Set the URL:
  url: 'end point url here',
  //Set the request body:
  body: JSON.stringify( 'request body here'
  }),
}, function(error, response, body){

  //Alert the response body:
  console.log(body);
  console.log(response.statusCode);
 });
}
```

I am getting a 401 error. I have done research and I believe its something to do with sending the IP address. Am I sending it correctly in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple. There is an issue in the Authorisation section of the request header. The line that reads:

```
'Authorization': "bearer "+ token,  //Bearer Token
```

Should be changed to:

```
'Authorization': "Bearer "+ token,  //Bearer Token
```

`Authorization` header is case sensitive. It needs to be capital otherwise you will be denied access.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical async problem. To send `ipAddress`, you need to guarantee it is already assigned a value first.

In your code:

```
var ipAddress;
publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
  ipAddress = ip;
  console.log(ip);
});
// code x
```

As `publicIp.v4()` is normally an async operation (query from OpenDNS for example), `code x` is executed before `ipAddress = ip;`, which means if your `request(...)` statement is right after `publicIp.v4().then(...)`, it will be executed with `ipAddress` as `undefined`.

Even if `request(...)` statement is executed somewhere else, some time later, there is no guarantee that `ipAddress` is ready -- `publicIp.v4().then(...)` may cost a lot of time.

To fix the issue, you need to put `request(...)` into the callback of async operation, such as:

```
var ipAddress;
publicIp.v4().then(ip => {
  ipAddress = ip;
  console.log(ip);
  request(...);
});
```